# django class based view pass url parameter in create post to current category

Tags: django, forms, templates, url, view

lets's say that i have three categories (tutorials, news, jobs).

and i have class based views to list all posts, list posts by category and  create new posts.

and sure post is the same model and fields to all categories.

**my problem is :**

if user was in category list template (let's say tutorial) .. i want the user when he create new post .. it is saved directly to tutorial category .. and if user was in list template (let's say news) .. he will create new post which will be saved directly to news category.

i mean create new post saved directly to current category.

i believe i will use (pass url parameter to class based views) but actually i failed to do that .. and i searched tonnage of questions without got what i want.

can any body help .. with sample please.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.name:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def PostListView(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    posts = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related().annotate(commentscountperpost=Count('comments'))
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related().annotate(total_product_category=Count('post'))
    if category_slug:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
        posts = posts.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'title': 'Home Page',
        'posts': posts,
        'total_posts': total_posts,
        'categories': categories,
        'category': category,}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/new_post.html'
    form_class = PostCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title')
    content = forms.CharField(label='Content', widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

**urls.py**

```
path('index_list/', PostListView, name='list'),
path('<slug:category_slug>', PostListView, name='post_category_list'),
path('new_post/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
```

**new_post.html template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="border p-4 mb-5">
    <legend class="border-bottom pb-1 mb-3">New Post </legend>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <input class="btn btn-secondary mt-4" type="submit" value="Add New Post">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**list.html template**

```
{% for category in categories %}
<h5><a class="text-primary" href="{% url 'post_category_list' category.slug %}">
    {{ category.name }} ({{ category.total_product_category }})</a></h5>
{% endfor %}
    <h5>{{ total_posts }} Total Posts </h5>
{% if category %}
    <a href="{% url 'new_post' %}">New {{ category }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: is there a form to create a post on the category detail page ?

Comment: no, there is no category details page, it is only page for post list per category , and it is included create new post button, and form fields as shown in my question in forms.py , and form inputs in new_post.html page. thanks for your support.

Comment: what does that mean post list per category ?

Comment: yes, i want to save the new post directly to  `category.slug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
 class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
       model = Post
       template_name = 'blog/new_post.html'
       form_class = CreatePostForm
       slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

       def form_valid(self, form):
          category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
          form.instance.category = category
          form.instance.author = self.request.user
          return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And in the urls

```
path('new_post/<slug>/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
```

Comment: unfortunately, it return `Reverse for 'new_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new_post/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']` and i tried to add `slug` or `slug.id` or `category` or `category.id` to url, but it return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

yes i found it , depending on arjun answer, greate thanks for arjun

in list posts per category template change :

```
<a href="{% url 'new_post' %}">New {{ category }}</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="{% url 'new_post' category.slug %}">New {{ category }}</a>
```

and it works fine,
thanks.